# Angular 2: JQuery UI Datepicker not changing ngModel

Tags: angular, jquery-ui-datepicker, angular2-ngmodel

I have JQuery UI's datepicker working in my angular 2 application, however it is not updating my `ngModel`. I have a variable called `SeasonStartDate`, which I want to update to whatever date the user inputs. When I select a date in my date picker, so October 31st for example, my input will fill with 10/31/2016, as I would expect, but `ngModel` isn't successfully updating.

Here is my input:

```
<input [ngModel]="SeasonStartDate" (ngModelChange)="updateSeasonStartDate($event)" class="form-control date-picker" id="SeasonStartDate" name="SeasonStartDate" type="text" autocomplete="off">
Date: {{SeasonStartDate}}
```

I added `Date: {{SeasonStartDate}}` below the input so I can test whether or not the value is updating.

Here is the code in my component that updates the value:

```
updateSeasonStartDate(updateSeasonStartDate: any) {
    console.log(updateSeasonStartDate);
    this.SeasonStartDate = updateSeasonStartDate;
}
```

If I remove the `date-picker` class (which is needed to initiate the date picker) and I just manually type in the input, `SeasonStartDate` will update as expected, so I know the rest of my code works, it's just the date picker that ends up breaking it. How can I get `ngModel` and JQuery UI Datepicker to work together? Is this possible? I know there are other date pickers out there specifically for Angular 2, but I prefer JQuery's version if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but I did find a way to make this work.

First, I updated my input to look like the following:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="SeasonStartDate" #startDate (click)="updateSeasonStartDate(startDate.value)" class="form-control date-picker" id="SeasonStartDate" name="SeasonStartDate" tabindex="5" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

The important changes are the additions of `#startDate` and `(click)="updateSeasonStartDate(startDate.value)"`

This says, when you click this input, invoke `updateSeasonStartDate()` and pass in whatever the current value of the input is. Now that alone won't give me the desired results, because I want to bind the value of the input to my `SeasonStartDate` variable anytime a new date is entered, not just when the input is clicked, which is why I also added the following code to the `ngOnInit` function:

```
$('body').on('change', '#SeasonStartDate', function() {    
    $('#SeasonStartDate').trigger('click');
});
```

Now anytime the value of that input changes, `updateSeasonStartDate()` will be invoked and change `SeasonStartDate` just like I want. This is definitely a hacky work around, and you might be wondering why I didn't simply put `(change)` instead of `(click)` in my input. That's because for whatever reason, the `(change)` event wouldn't register when the value of the input changed while using JQuery Date Picker. I don't know if this is a bug with Angular 2, or if it is intended behavior, but it's the only way I could get it to work.

If anyone has better solutions, please let me know and I will accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using JqueryUI datepicker, you can tell the datepicker what to do in the event onSelect. Give it a fuction that assigns the selected date to the model.

```
     $('#SeasonStartDate').datepicker({
         onSelect: (selectedDate, inst) => {
             this.SeasonStartDate= selectedDate;
         }
     });
```

Comment: Straightest solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need to detect the change of the input and instead need the value when an event occurs you could use ViewChild to update the value of your date variable when that event happens.

For example in my case, when I submit the form I set the value of the date.

My input:

```
<input type="text" id="date-picker-example" #dateclass="form-control pickadate" #date>
```

I use ViewChild and this is my input declaration:

```
@ViewChild('date')
dateVariable: any;
```

Then when submit occurs:

```
submit(){
   this.myRealDateVariable = this.resolveDate(this.dateVariable.nativeElement.value);
   //Rest of the code here calling an http service
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late answer, but I found a way to make it work without "hacky" methods. Just import jquery before angular! The ngModel will instantly recognize the date picked in jQuery's datepicker.

It worked for me in angularJS (1.6.4).